# Getting nothing while parsing xml

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter, xmlpullparser

**I am trying to parse xml file with next structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <tag1 id="92">
        <tag11>Some text for parsing</tag11>
        <tag12 src="http://some_valid_url_with_image" />
    </tag1>
    <tag2 attr1="111111" attr2="222222" attr2="333333">
        <tag21>Some text for parsing 2</tag21>
        <tag22 attr1="4444444">Some text for parsing 3</tag22>
        <tag23 attr1="5555555">Some text for parsing 4</tag23>
        <tag24 attr1="32">Some text for parsing 5</tag24>
        <tag25 attr1="21">Some text for parsing 6</tag25>
    </tag2>
</root>
```

**I am using XMLPullParser with switch-case construction and my own Adapter:**

```
public class XMLParse extends AppCompatActivity {
    String tagname = "";
    String tagtext = "";
    String tag11 = "tag11";
    String tag12 = "tag12";
    String tag12VALUE = "";

    public Bitmap myBitmap;

    private List<SomeItem> items = new ArrayList();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        IV = findViewById(R.id.iconsrc);
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.myxml);

            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                switch (parser.getEventType()){
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT :
                        tagtext = parser.getText();
                        if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(tag11)) {
                            items.add(new SomeItem(tagtext, IV));
                        }
                        if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(tag12)){
                            tag12VALUE = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                            InputStream input = new URL(tag12VALUE).openStream();
                            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                            IV.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                         break;

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        tagname = parser.getName();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        tagname = parser.getName();
                        break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Error while loading xml document: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        SomeItemAdapter adapter = new SomeItemAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**Here is my Adapter:**

```
public class SomeItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeItem>{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private List<SomeItem> items;

    public SomeItemAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<SomeItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items= items;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

        ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.iconsrc);
        TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);

            SomeItem item = items.get(position);

            //i think here i must TODO some code with ImageView and TextView, 
smth like setImageResource and setText, but how I can do this If I getting my text and image while parsing?

            return view;
        }
    }
```

**The last class, with my Item:**

```
public class SomeItem{

    private String name;
    private ImageView iconsrc;

    public SomeItem(String name, ImageView iconsrc){

        this.name=name;
        this.iconsrc=iconsrc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ImageView getIconResource() {
        return this.iconsrc;
    }

    public void setIconResource(ImageView iconsrc) {
        this.iconsrc = iconsrc;
    }

}
```

list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconsrc"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am expecting to get ListView with image, which URL is parsing from xml and to get some text from tag in this xml.
But actually I am getting nothing in my ListView.

As I wrote in code, I think I am not property did my Adapter, so the main question is: what is wrong in my code and how I can get ListView with parsed data?

***UPD:***
Problem with text in list view solved, but now I have problem with image loading:

```
if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(tag12)){
```

Here tagname = tag11, why? I should call parser.next() somewhere else or what?

Comment: if the problem is load image maybe you can use [fresco library](https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html). In fact you can load url String on imageView.

Comment: why I should use library If I had Bitmap?

Comment: Library help to load image on ImageView from String values. You can load TextView  like `nameView.setText(items.get(position).getName());` It's easy, try to load ImageView

Comment: Now I am getting error only with loading image to list view because here: `if (tagname != null && tagname.equals(tag12)){` variable tagname = tag11 (where is no attribute with url), but not tag12 where is my url.

Comment: `icon.setImageBitmap(item.getIconResource());` I've tried this for loading Bitmap

Comment: but pls read my previous comment about tagname, now I will edit my question with this information.

Comment: edited question (UPD).